# What is it about AA and Danish Collation?

Tags: perl, multilingual, collation

I have the following Perl script, intended to show collation in Danish.

```
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin/perl

use 5.014_001;
use utf8;
use Unicode::Collate;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Data::Dump;
use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;


binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my @words =("AAI Document Type", "Apple", "Zebra");

my $coll = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(locale => "da");

my @result = $coll->sort(@words);


foreach my $item (@result){
print $item, "\n";
}
```

It outputs

```
Apple
Zebra
AAI Document Type
```

Why does "AAI Document Type" go to the end? There seems to be something about "AA" that triggers this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AA` is treated as a single letter in Danish, also written as `Å`.

Details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet#History).

Obviously in an abbreviation like `AAI`, treating the `AA` as `Å` isn't appropriate (it really is two `A` characters). I suppose the way to avoid that would be to use a different collation.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose this is a pitfall of mixing languages in technical documentation.