# SQL Like single letter with wildcard

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with a SQL query to SQL Database. I can't simple find out why.

I will like to get all the rows there ShortName contains 'A'.

The ShortName column has datatype `nvarchar(max)`.

My table look like this:

[image]

If i do this query on the database: 
`SELECT ID, ShortName FROM Airports where ShortName LIKE '%A%';`

Results:
[image]

If I do this query: 
`SELECT ID, ShortName FROM Airports where ShortName LIKE '%AA%';`

Results:
[image]

As you can se it not takes all the rows there shortname contains 'A'.
But why? I have searching for the answer, but I can't find it.

Comment: So why `'%A%'` does *not* return `AAR` and `AAL` ?

Comment: Yes thats simple the question

Comment: You have a typo.  You put %aa% in the second try.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your first query should return many more rows. However why on earth would you store a three letter code in a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field?

Comment: are you sure you have the same `A` in all strings? because it's possible, for example, to have cyryllic A in one string and latin in others..

Comment: showing cast(shortname as varbinary(max)) will confirm this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I know that the data types and lengths are not optimal, it is because it is a EF code first project and that the models have not been optimized yet.

Comment: I'm with Nick on this.  NVarChar(Max) is generally only used for "Memo" type fields, and is a waste of space on your server.  You should be using Char(3).  As for the original question, I'd lean towards it being an issue with cyryllic vs non-cyryllic as pointed out by several other people.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257974/what-is-it-about-aa-and-danish-collation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your are in Scandinavia, your database default collation is most likely Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS. This will cause AA to be interpeted as Å

So for your query to work, use:

```
SELECT ID, ShortName FROM Airports 
where ShortName LIKE '%A%' 
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to which collation you use in the database, I would guess because AA can be interepetated differently in some language (Danish for example)
If you do the following you'll get different result for each of the selects.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (v VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('AAR')
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE v COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CS_AS LIKE '%A%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CS_AS

SELECT * FROM @t WHERE v COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI LIKE '%A%' COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI
```

This gives me result AAR from the first and nothing in this second.

Answer (score 0):

Could you script the table and the data?

If I do this:

```
SELECT CAST(1 as int) AS ID, CAST('AAR' AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS ShortName INTO #Airports

INSERT INTO #Airports
SELECT 2, 'CPH' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'STA' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'AAL' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'CNL' UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'ZGH' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'ROD' UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'KRP' 

SELECT * FROM #Airports a
SELECT ID, ShortName FROM #Airports where ShortName LIKE '%A%';
SELECT ID, ShortName FROM #Airports where ShortName LIKE '%AA%';
```

I do get expected results:

```
         ID ShortName
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
          2 CPH
          3 STA
          4 AAL
          5 CNL
          6 ZGH
          7 ROD
          8 KRP
          1 AAR

(8 row(s) affected)

         ID ShortName
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
          3 STA
          4 AAL
          1 AAR

(3 row(s) affected)

         ID ShortName
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
          4 AAL
          1 AAR

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score -1):

strange , when I execute your first query:

```
CREATE TABLE  testtt
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ShortName nvarchar(max),
);

insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('AAR');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('BLL');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('CPH');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('EBJ');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('KRP');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('ODE');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('RKE');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('RNN');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('SGD');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('SKS');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('TED');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('STA');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('AAL');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('CNL');
insert into testtt (ShortName) values ('WGH');


SELECT ID, ShortName
FROM testtt
WHERE ShortName LIKE '%A%'

SELECT * FROM Testtt
```

I get the desired results though..